# Swift create one Int array from two int arrays by taking the max() at each index

Tags: arrays, swift

I feel like this may call for `reduce`, `map` or something like it to solve but I'm not yet familiar enough with these and was hoping someone here might be.  Lets say I have

`arrayOne = [1, 3, 7] 
arrayTwo = [2, 1, 10]`

the expected result for what I'm trying to do would be

`mergedArray = [2, 3, 10]`

I know I can do this with a relatively simple for loop in a method but I am looking for a more "swift" way to do it if it's possible.

And Yes, both arrays will always be the same length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
let arrayOne = [1, 3, 7]
let arrayTwo = [2, 1, 10]

let mergedArray = zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo).map{max($0, $1)}
```

First, pair each element in two arrays with `zip`, and then use `map` to each pair.

Comment: Even shorter: `zip(arrayOne, arrayTwo).map(max)`